# Azure webapp, setting CURRENT_STACK

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I have created many webapps through ARM, not setting Current Stack, and by apps run just fine. Today i tried to create a webapp through the portal, and i could see that I could download the ARM template. I got curious, and did it, and I saw that the portal set this

```
"metadata": [
            {
               "name": "CURRENT_STACK",
               "value": "[parameters('currentStack')]"
            }
]
```

Does this even matter? Have I always done my ARM templates wrong? My heart skipped a bit. Does my websites actually run on some other obscure framework? When I visit "General Settings" on one of my webapps I can see it is being set to .NET v4.7. Does this mean that it runs .NET 4.7 even though i am deploying .NET Core to it?

It think this is very confusing!

I cant find this documented *anywhere*, not even  here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sites.

I have actually done this once before (going through portal, downloading the ARM) because i wanted to know how to set the stack setting: [Azure webapp: Stack settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392312/azure-webapp-stack-settings) - but it didn't show up at that time.

Should I start doing this now?

Answer (score -3):

```
    #Properties
$PropertiesObject = @{
    "CURRENT_STACK" =  "dotnetcore"
 }



New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $metadata `
    -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```

Comment: Mentioning only code does not help, you have to describe the why and how of the solution you are providing.

Comment: Does it even matter setting this? That is what I want to know.